# What's the difference between nam and enim?

Tags: conjunction, nuance

Both *nam* and *enim* are generally defined as meaning "for," the only difference between them being that *nam* comes first in a clause and that *enim* is postpositive (i.e., it comes second).

Is there a semantic difference between them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I posted this question here because it was something I struggled with for a long, long time, right up until I read [Caroline Kroon](http://www.uva.nl/en/news-events/news/uva-news/content/professor-appointments/2013/08/caroline-kroon-professor-of-latin-language-and-literature.html)'s article "Latin Particles and the Grammar of Discourse" in *[A Companion to the Latin Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1405186054)*, ed. James Clackson.

The difference between the two isn't so much semantic as it is . . . dí immortálés, I'm terrible with terms . . . about discourse?

Basically, *nam* has a narrative function, where *enim* has a dialogical one. With *nam*, the speaker is simply informing the listener of what he believes to be a causal relationship between two facts. With *enim*, the speaker is indicating that he thinks the listener is on the same page as he is. I've found the easiest translations of *enim*, then, to be "y'know," or "right?" (in questions), or even "after all."

> *Dídó sibi mortem cónscívit, nam ab Ænéá relicta erat.*
>   Dido killed herself, for she had been left by Aeneas.

There I'm simply telling you the facts.

> *Dídó sibi mortem cónscívit, ab enim Ænéá relicta erat.*
>   Dido killed herself; she had been left by Aeneas, after all.

There I'm showing you an assumption I'm making that you believe as I do.

Think of *enim* as being accompanied by a knowing shrug or a nod of the head that invites the listener to agree.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to format questions/answers beyond a basic level, so if anybody feels the impulse to do so here, please be my guest.

Comment: "about discourse" = [*discursive* (definition 3)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discursive)?

Comment: Hmm. That makes me think "rambling" or "roundabout." The two terms I'm thinking of are "pragmatic" and "illocutionary," but both of them have specific linguistic meanings and I don't understand them well enough to know which, if either, is more appropriate.

Comment: Should the second speaker in "the speaker is indicating that he thinks the speaker is on the same page as he is" be listening instead of speaking?

Comment: Indeed it should, and now it does!

Comment: "Discourse-pragmatic", though clunky, is a term that used in linguistics for "about discourse" in this sense.

Answer (score 5):

I was recently reading Karl Gottlob Zumpt's excellent [*Grammar of the Latin Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vosAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=conjunctions&source=web&ots=dIYi7uXN28&sig=Q8UQ7e1zL697wZgG1oq4lah324Q#v=onepage&q=conjunctions&f=false), which contains an extensive section on conjunctions and their differences (pp. 250ff).

His distinctions are largely the same as the above answer, but it might help to shed some more light for those who are still confused:

Besides the practical difference that *nam* begins a clause while *enim* is postpositive, he states:

> The difference in meaning seems to consist in this, that *nam* introduces a **conclusive reason**, and *enim* merely a **confirming circumstance**, the consideration of which depends upon the inclination of the speaker. *Nam*, therefore, denotes an objective reason, and *enim* merely a subjective one.

Comment: It's funny—I've read Zumpt about 400 times, and neither this nor practically any of the other stuff on conjunctions ever made any sense to me. It still kind of doesn't—I'm delighted that there are others for whom that isn't the case!

Comment: @JoelDerfner, Did I say I wasn't confused? :)